# Can a MovieClip be added to Listbox? Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For making an online users list (Example at http://www.flashchatdeluxe.com/flash_chat_video_edition.html). Each username is actually a movieclip with their name, photo, etc. So if there were 3 users online, there would be 3 of these movieclips in the list.

So can a MovieClip be added to a regular Flash Listbox component or how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest option is to use a [TileList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TileList.html) since by default it uses an [ImageCell](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/ImageCell.html) as it's source renderer and you can simply pass your MovieClip as the source propert of an item passed to list's data provider:

```
import fl.controls.TileList;
var tl:TileList = addChild(new TileList()) as TileList;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) tl.addItem({label:"user"+(i+1),source:yourClip});
```

Otherwise feel free to implement your custom cell renderer.